# Disable Warn from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, nlog

Application -> .NET Core

LogAdapter  -> Nlog

[image]
With this config , it is still  log the Warn from Entity Framework. What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted the example NLog.config from the Wiki-tutorial:

```
  <rules>   
    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Warn" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="Db_WebLog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

From wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having your first line writeTo, use it as a rule to filter out what you want to ignore.

See the documentation for this [here](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#example-rules)

The code that'll work will be this:

```
<logger name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*" level="Warn" final="true" />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="Db_WebLog" />
```

The first rule selects loggers, but since there is no writeTo, these messages are not logged. And, since this rule contains 'final=true', the last rule does not apply to loggers matching the first rule.